# logrotate and rsyslog no rotation or double rotation

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

i have a confusing problem.
i have a syslog server with rsyslogd who collect/get the logs from my servers and save them in `/var/log/servers/Year/month/servername/`, and I have a logrotate script who runs every hour with config

```
/var/log/servers/Year/month/servername/*[!.gz]
{
        rotate 20
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y%m%d_%H:%M
        missingok
        size 200M
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
                find /var/log/servers/Year/month/ -name "*.gz" -mtime +5 -delete
        endscript
}
```

My problem now is that its sometimes makes something like these:
`/var/log/servers/Year/month/messages_20210427-10:05_20210427-11:05_....` and so on and sometimes it doesn’t rotate the logs so there climbing into GB big files and filling my disk so I have no more space. Does anybody have a helping idea?

Greetings

Comment: The file looks ok to me. Please recheck the input data you have. If the problem still occurs, create [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. In this case, use a path like `/tmp/foo`, start stripping parameters until you get as minimal as possible file. Test log file probably can generated with `dd`, or just copy a file for testing.

Comment: Hi smar, already thanks for try to help me. i already give any information i have :/
I have the feeling that rsyslog is locking the files and because of that they cant get rotated. and abot the re rotating error, i could thinks about that my splunk is reading the file and because of that these happens, but when that happend ones it happens every time until the file name gets too long and logrotate can rotate it anymore
i use all these parameters becuase i tried to correct the problems. it get definitely better but still happens, first i forgot gz exclusion :D